# Recovering a (not yet created) RAID5 with URE (Unrecoverable read errors)

Tags: linux, hard-disk, raid, mdadm, software-raid

I wan't to create a RAID5 array at home, the OS is Linux (Kernel 3.15.7) and the array will be created with `mdadm`. I wan't to create the array with eigth or ten 1TB discs.

Let's assume a single drive fails, according to the internet, the chance of a URE during the reconstruction is very high.

Can't I just ignore the URE? I mean the URE doesn't affect the whole disc, only one sector (AFAIK) and so one RAID stripe.

Can I reconstruct the array with errors (,So I only lose some files and can recover the filesystem with `fsck`)?

What happens if array is only partly filled with data and the URE happens in empty drive space?

Are there better alternatives for RAID5? I've read about ZFS and RAID-Z, but ZFS isn't included in the mainstream kernel and it's not complete open source (AFAIK).

I don't want to use RAID10 or RAID01 because with such RAIDs I can only use half of the total disc space.

Answer (score 0):

The chance of a URE during the reconstruction is very high?! What utter rubbish.

Well, it's true - if you are stupid and never ever test your hard disks for errors! In that case, the resync is your first ever full read test for all other drives. Since read errors can go undiscovered for ages, naturally the risk of finding one such at rebuild time is high.

RAID relies on healthy drives, and you have to test your disks regularly. Detect problems early, replace faulty hardware quickly. Don't keep disks that reallocate sectors or show other problems.

> Can't I just ignore the URE?

Well. `md` itself does not ignore it (what is it supposed to do, invent unreadable data? Silently zero and corrupt your stuff without reporting errors?), but nothing is stopping you from using `ddrescue` or similar. So yes, you can ignore it, using tools that do so consciously with known side effects.

> What happens if array is only partly filled with data and the URE happens in empty drive space?

`md` has no notion of what's empty and what's not. It's just a block device.

> Are there better alternatives for RAID5?

If you need more redundancy, RAID6, but if you don't monitor your drives, it will die too. Disks fail. Make sure you notice and replace immediately.